# Taking user input for selecting Chart Template in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I've a rudimentary solution for creating Excel charts per row of data.

I have the following code ("ark" = "sheet"):

```
Sub CreateColumnClustered()
       'variable declaration
        Dim i As Long
        Dim LastRow As Long
        Dim LastColumn As Long
        Dim chrt As Chart

        'last row used
        LastRow = Sheets("Ark1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

        'last column used
        LastColumn = Sheets("Ark1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

        'Looping from row nr. 2 to last row
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            'Select Ark 2 where charts will be inserted
            Sheets("Ark2").Select

            'Clear cell selection
            Cells(1, 1).Select

            'Add charts to ark
            Set chrt = Sheets("Ark2").Shapes.AddChart.Chart
            'chart type
            chrt.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
            'chart template
            chrt.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
            "PATH_TO_CHART_TEMPLATE")

            'establish data source
            With Sheets("Ark1")
                chrt.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, LastColumn))
                chrt.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Ark1'!$B$1:$G$1"
            End With

            'anchor position of charts
            chrt.ChartArea.Left = 1
            chrt.ChartArea.Top = (i - 2) * chrt.ChartArea.Height

            Next

    End Sub
```

This works for the users, except they are unable to specify their own templates.

I am looking for a way for the user to specify their own .crtx file.

I would like to avoid multiple macros, each with their own hardcoded template file.

Comment: Look at `Application.Getopenfilename` to allow the user to choose the template to use.

Comment: another option is to have the user enter the file path in a cell and reference that cell for the template file to use

Comment: @Rory. Thank you for both of your inputs. I ended up using the example of `Application.Getopenfilename` provided here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh710200(v=office.14).aspx. Combined with in-workbook button objects, the end-users are comfortable working with the solution. Do I accept your answer (Rory) or do I post my complete code and accept myself?

Comment: Post your code and accept that. Mine was just a comment rather than a complete answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT**: I ended up using `Application.GetOpenFilename` and passing that output as a string for `ApplyChartTemplate`

This is the final code: (Note "PATH_TO_DIR" needs changing to whatever (if any) custom path you would like to utilize)

```
Sub Select_File_Or_Files_Windows()
    Dim SaveDriveDir As String
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim chrt As Chart

    ' Save the current directory.
    SaveDriveDir = CurDir

    ' Set the path to the folder that you want to open.
    ' MyPath = Application.DefaultFilePath

    ' You can also use a fixed path.
    MyPath = "PATH_TO_DIR"

    ' Change drive/directory to MyPath.
    ChDrive MyPath
    ChDir MyPath

    ' Open GetOpenFilename with the file filters.
    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename

    ' Change drive/directory back to SaveDriveDir.
    ChDrive SaveDriveDir
    ChDir SaveDriveDir

    'Find the last used row
    LastRow = Sheets("Ark1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last used column
    LastColumn = Sheets("Ark1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

    'Looping from second row till last row which has the data
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        'Sheet 2 is selected bcoz charts will be inserted here
        Sheets("Ark2").Select

        'Clear cell selection
        Cells(1, 1).Select

        'Adds chart to the sheet
        Set chrt = Sheets("Ark2").Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        'sets the chart type
        chrt.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        chrt.ApplyChartTemplate (CStr(Fname))

        'now the line chart is added...setting its data source here
        With Sheets("Ark1")
            chrt.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, LastColumn))
            chrt.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Ark1'!$B$1:$G$1"
        End With

        'Left & top are used to adjust the position of chart on sheet
        chrt.ChartArea.Left = 1
        chrt.ChartArea.Top = (i - 2) * chrt.ChartArea.Height

        Next

End Sub
```